# Onkyo subwoofer amp, disable automatic power toggling

Tags: amplifier, audio

I have this subwoofer that turns on and off based on if there is signal on the input. It's real annoying that I will be watching something quiet, it will turn off, and then later it will turn on again when something happens with bass. It takes a couple of seconds to kick on, so it misses what it supposed to come through the woofer.

I have a schematic. I have no idea on where to start. I cannot grasp when there are like a dozen transistors and they all interact with each other and pull things to ground or VCC. I tried removing Q901 and installing a jumper to ground...to no avail. No idea what I'm doing. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It seems like the easiest way will be to remove C601 and connecting the R601 "upper" leg to pin 8 of a Q301.

Comment: Or removing D651 and connect the lower end of  R651 to GND (0V).

Comment: You can also try to "short" Q606 collector to +5V rail.

Comment: I was considering removing C601 but didn't quite know where to safely connect the upper leg of R601. This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the easiest way will be to remove C601 and connecting the R601 "upper" leg to pin 8 of a Q301 or short Q603 to ground.

Answer (score 1):

Jumpering P631 will disable auto standby.