# Onkyo SKW-320 subwoofer, want to disable auto power off toggling

Tags: circuit-analysis

I own an Onkyo SKW-320 subwoofer and the auto standby kicks in fairly regularly and can take a few seconds to come back on meaning I miss some bass audio cues etc. I'm wondering if anyone would be good enough as to tell me which component I need to remove, ground or bridge to disable the auto standby for good, I can perform the work but wouldn't be able to work out what's what in regards that section!
I noticed a thread from 2018 where the part in question was figured out and worked but that was for a different model and doesn't follow the same circuit by looks of it. I'm enclosing a copy of the PC board from the service manual for anyone to look over and point out the relevant section I need to look at etc. Thanks for looking.[image: SKW-320 PC Board]

The manual can be found at the following link if it's not possible to read the picture closeup - [SKW-320 Service Manual](https://elektrotanya.com/onkyo_skw-320_sm.pdf/download.html#dl)

EDIT: - [Link to original mod on different model sub](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388357/onkyo-subwoofer-amp-disable-automatic-power-toggling)

Comment: Hi there! If you don't mind, edit question and add link to that other mod.

Comment: start by reading the amplifier IC datasheet

Comment: @MiNiMe Done but for clarity it's - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388357/onkyo-subwoofer-amp-disable-automatic-power-toggling

Comment: @jsotola I've been trying that but getting lost, i've got all stuff/info open and trying to follow from one to try and copy it to the other but I can't quite follow it.

Comment: Thanks. Please tell me that this standby operation of the subwoofer is faulty, something's that developed over time?

Comment: @MiNiMe No, not faulty, I just don't want it as it messes up audio from my PC as my PC doesn't always make a sound but when it does the sub is slow to kick in so I miss some sub audio, it sometimes flickers on/off as well due to low signal noise I guess. I don't care about electricity costs, I can easily push the button to turn it off if I want to, I used to run my old Z5500's 24/7 so I have no problem turning this sub in to the same.

Comment: @MiNiMe  Looking over the schematics and trying to follow from 2 circuits plus the IC datasheets my guess is it 'might' be C341 I need to remove and then run the R305 leg somewhere but i'm not 100% sure where (maybe pin 8 of IC301-B which is a JR4558 or pin 4 of IC401-A which is a LM2902 or equivalent) or even if i'm on the right track.

Comment: try shorting R370

Comment: To solve everything, I'll pull some bs here - bs ac plug.

Comment: I can't find C341 anywhere, closest to R305 is C351, I guess you mean that one.

Comment: I'd say jstolas solution is the most simple solution, then Peters.

Comment: @MiNiMe Yes sorry, I meant C351 but looks like I might've been well off the mark! I'm gonna give Peters fix a go 1st as it's only removing 1 part so can't harm anything, if that doesn't work i'll put it back and try shorting R370. Thanks again all for taking a look and offering me advice, appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the TDA7293 datasheet, it will be muted/disabled when pins 9 and 10 are pulled low, so I would just remove Q303.  R378 will then pull those inputs high.

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with your amplifier or the TDA7293 - I just read the datasheet and looked at the schematic.

Comment: I will give this method a try 1st as it sounds like it'd be the easiest without adding anything if all I need to do is remove Q303, at least then if it doesn't work for any reason I can just put it back as it were and move on to the next possible fix. Thanks for looking in to that for me, i'd have totally missed that!

Comment: It might be easier to place a short across R377 - that would hold Q303 off, and would be less destructive than removing the transistor.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that one. Can I go about it the following way? Rather than taking the R377 out of circuit and/or bridging over could I just run a wire from the bottom of R377 ground side and connect that to the leg of R376 so I can put it back to normal if I was to sell it on?

Comment: Whatever will hold the base of Q303 at or near Ground will work.